# I need some help deleting some elements in an vector. or maybe swapping c++

Tags: c++

I need some help with deleting some elements in a vector in some case blocks.

basically I used `vector::erase`, `std::move`, `std::swap` and many other things. none of them worked. the things that got deleted were displayed on the screen with the same elements. so what I need help to do is delete some elements in the vector.

I vector erase also gives me a segmentation fault.

also here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
using namespace std;
string world_name;
int i;
string dead2;
int index[50] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48} ;
int rand_index = index[rand()%50];
vector<string> name_list(50);
struct player_data {
} player_name;
cout << "Pick the name of your world" << endl;
for(auto& s: name_list) cin>>s;
cin >> world_name;
for (i = 1; i <= 5000; i++)
switch(rand()%40)
{
            case 0:
        break;
            rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " runs away from the " << world_name << endl;
            break;
            case 1:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " grabs a shield leaning on " << world_name << endl;
            break;
            case 2:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " retrieves a trident from inside " << world_name << endl;
            break;
            case 3:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " runs into the " << world_name << endl;
            break;
            case 4:
            rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index];
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << " and " << name_list[rand_index] << " work together to drown ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << endl;
        name_list[rand_index].erase (name_list[rand_index].begin()+rand()%50);
            break;
            case 5:
            rand_index = index[rand()%50];
        cout << name_list[rand_index] << " grabs a jar of fishing bait while ";
            rand_index = index[rand()%50];
        cout << name_list[rand_index] << " gets fishing gear" << endl;
            break;
            case 6:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << "and";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " hunt for other tributes" << endl;
            break;
            case 7:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " attacks ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " but they manage to escape" << endl;
            break;
            case 8:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " shoots a poisonous blow dart into ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << "'s" << " neck slowly killing them" << endl;
        break;
            case 9:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " forces ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " to kill ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " or ";
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " they decide to kill " << name_list[rand_index] << endl;
        name_list[rand_index].erase (name_list[rand_index].begin()+rand()%50);
        break;
        case 10:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " decapitates ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " with a sword" << endl;
        break;
            case 11:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " defeats ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " in a fight, but spares their life" << endl;
            break;
            case 12:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " lets ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " into their shelter" << endl;
            break;
            case 13:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " tends to ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << "'s" << " wounds" << endl;
            break;
            case 14:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << "and";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " tell stories about themselves to each other" << endl;
            break;
            case 15:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << ",";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << ",";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << " and " << name_list[rand_index] << " sleep in shifts" << endl;
            break;
            case 16:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " and ";
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " tell each other ghost stories to lighten the mood" << endl;
            break;
            case 17:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " clutches a first aid kit and runs away" << endl;
            break;
            case 18:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " takes a handful of throwing knives" << endl;
            case 19:
            break;
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " snaches a bottle of alcohol and a rag" << endl;
            break;
            case 20:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " finds a backpack full of camping equipment" << endl;
            break;
            case 21:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " grabs a backpack, not realizing it is empty" << endl;
            break;
            case 22:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " snaches a pair of sais" << endl;
            break;
            case 23:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " receives explosives from an unkown sponsor" << endl;
            break;
            case 24:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " finds a bow, some arrows, and a quiver." << endl;
            break;
            case 25:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " steps off his podium too soon and blows up."<< endl;
        break;
            case 26:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " grabs a shovel." << endl;
            break;
        case 27:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " runs away with a lighter and some rope." << endl;
            break;
            case 28:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " grabs a sword." << endl;
            break;
            case 29:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " finds a canteen full of water." << endl;
            break;
            case 30:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " practices their archery," << endl;
            break;
            case 31:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " makes a wooden spear." << endl;
            break;
            case 32:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " questions their sanity" << endl;
            break;
            case 33:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " camouflages themself in the bushes," << endl;
            break;
            case 34:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " collects fruit from a tree" << endl;
            break;
            case 35:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " travels to highter ground" << endl;
            break;
            case 36:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " sees smoke rising in the distance, but decides not to investigate," << endl;
            break;
            case 37:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " receives a hatchet from an unknown sponsor," << endl;
            break;
            case 38:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " thinks about winning" << endl;
            break;
            case 39:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50]; 
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " attempts to start a fire, but is unsuccessful" << endl;
            break;
            case 40:
        rand_index = index[rand()%50];
            cout << name_list[rand_index] << " screams for help" << endl;
}
}                

                                  `                                                                                                                                                                                                                   216,11-18     98%
```

￼

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'd advise not to use std::vector if you intended to remove random elements from it.
Use std::map<std::string, player_data> instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the size as `50` everywhere, use it as `name_list.size()`. The size of your vector is not fixed during the whole runtime.

Since you're running the loop 5000 times, I would also recommend you to add a check when the size of vector becomes 0.

Also your case 40 will never execute, change to `switch(rand() % 41)` to have all cases covered up.

Comment: i think i kinda got it working but one issue, near the end the names disappear and sometimes in the middle too: finds a bow, some arrows, and a quiver.
 attacks  but they manage to escape
 and  work together to drown 
 grabs a jar of fishing bait while t gets fishing gear
 forces  to kill  or  they decide to kill

Comment: @AdamChristopher @AdamChristopher That's why I had suggested adding check when size becomes 0. Just before your switch add a line `if (name_list.empty()) { cout << All players dead!" << endl; break; } else switch .....